# GMSMapView myLocation not giving actual location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a GMSMapView properly loaded and working inside my viewcontroller

what i'm not being able to do is setting the GMSCameraPosition around my location

this is my code:

```
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
CLLocation* myLoc = [mapView_ myLocation];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLoc.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:myLoc.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:4];
[mapView_ setCamera:camera];
```

GPS is enabled and application has all needed permissions but myLocation returns a nil CLLocation, consequentially `cameraWithLatitude:longitude:zoom:` get 0 0  coordinates and displays Africa instead of my actual location (that is not in africa :) )

Answer (score 13):

From official Google Maps iOS SDK documentation:

> - (BOOL) myLocationEnabled [read, write, assign]
>     Controls whether the My Location dot and accuracy circle is enabled.
>
> Defaults to NO.
>
> - (CLLocation*) myLocation [read, assign]
>     If My Location is enabled, reveals where the user location dot is being drawn.
>
> If it is disabled, or it is enabled but no location data is available, this will be nil. This property is observable using KVO.

So when you set `mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;`, it only tells the `mapView` to reveal the blue dot only if you have a location value given to the `myLocation` property. The sample code from Google shows how to observe the user location using the KVO method.(Recommended) You can also implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method, to update the mapView.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [mapView animateToLocation:newLocation.coordinate];
    // some code...
}
```

Here are the code from google maps sample code on how to use KVO to update user location.

```
// in viewDidLoad method...
// Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
  [mapView_ addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];
// Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  });

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if (!firstLocationUpdate_) {
    // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
    // location.
    firstLocationUpdate_ = YES;
    CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    mapView_.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                     zoom:14];
  }
}
```

Comment: is your firstLocationUpdate_ variable just a boolean property?

Comment: @kevinl yes, actually, the second code snippets are copied from google sample code...

Comment: can't believe Google didn't include a method in GMSMapViewDelegate, using KVO is kinda hacking in this case...

Answer (score -4):

Try to using MapKit, under the **VieDidLoad** or **ViewWillApper** using:

```
myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

You can add this simple code under the IBAction if you want, like a :

```
- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender{

         myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: i need to use google maps, and MapKit and GMS are in any way working together

Comment: but mapKit using a google map and i think but not sure have the same method like a 'showUserLocation' or 'getUserLocation' then you can add zoom and 'coordinate.latitude' & 'longitude'