# How do I simulate location for xctest

Tags: ios, google-maps, testing, core-location

I'm trying to write some unit tests (using xctest) that verify that my Google Maps mapView is centered on my "current location".

```
- (void) testMapCentersOnMyLocation {
  WtHomeController *controller = [[WtHomeController alloc] init];
  [controller viewDidLoad];

  //Simulator's location is stubbed to be in San Francisco, at this lat/lon
  CLLocationDegrees expectedLatitude = 37.787359f;
  CLLocationDegrees expectedLongitude = -122.408227f;

  // FIXME this loop runs forever - location isn't being updated in simulator.      
  while(controller.firstLocationUpdate == NO) {
    NSLog(@"Waiting on location...");
    NSLog(@"my location is: %f, %f", controller.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude, controller.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
  }

  CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenter = [controller.mapView.camera target];
  XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(mapCenter.latitude, expectedLatitude, 0.00001f);
  XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(mapCenter.longitude, expectedLongitude, 0.00001f);

}
```

Here are the relevant methods from the controller that is allocating the mapView

```
@interface WtHomeController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL firstLocationUpdate;

@end

@implementation WtHomeController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //Initialize map pane on Los Angeles lat/lon
  CLLocationDegrees latitude = WtLosAngelesLatitude;
  CLLocationDegrees longitude = WtLosAngelesLongitude;

  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                          longitude:longitude
                                                               zoom:6];

  self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;


  // Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
  [self.mapView addObserver:self
                 forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                    context:NULL];


  self.view = self.mapView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [self.mapView removeObserver:self
                    forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                       context:NULL];
}    

#pragma mark - KVO updates


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

  DDLogDebug(@"my location is: %f, %f", self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude);

  if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"] ) {
    if (!self.firstLocationUpdate) {
      // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
      // location.
      self.firstLocationUpdate = YES;
      CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
      self.mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                       zoom:14];
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I've figured out so far: I can simulate location when I build my app by editing the scheme preferences in Xcode.

[image: Screenshot of editing Location Simulation]

Then, when I build the app from xcode, I can see in the simulator that my location get's updated to "San Francisco". Here's the output from the log when I build and run on the simulator:

```
2014-04-02 17:28:09.253 DEBUG WtHomeController: observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: 109 - my location is: 37.787359, -122.408227
```

Cool. But when running the unit tests, my location never gets updated.

Output from the test log is:

```
2014-04-02 17:02:41.919 wetap[71081:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 17:02:41.919 wetap[71081:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-04-02 17:02:41.919 wetap[71081:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 17:02:41.920 wetap[71081:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-04-02 17:02:41.920 wetap[71081:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 17:02:41.921 wetap[71081:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-04-02 17:02:41.921 wetap[71081:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 17:02:41.921 wetap[71081:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
...to infinity
```

How do I simulate the location for my unit tests?

Edited my test per @Paulw11's suggestion:

```
  WtAppDelegate *appdelegate = (WtAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  CLLocationManager *locationManager = appdelegate.locationManager;
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  while(controller.firstLocationUpdate == NO) {
    NSLog(@"Waiting on location...");
    NSLog(@"my location is: %f, %f", controller.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude, controller.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"Location manager think's we're at: %@",  [locationManager location]);
  }
```

And the new log output from running that test:

```
2014-04-02 18:08:56.394 wetap[73922:60b] Location manager think's we're at: (null)
2014-04-02 18:08:56.394 wetap[73922:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 18:08:56.394 wetap[73922:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-04-02 18:08:56.395 wetap[73922:60b] Location manager think's we're at: (null)
2014-04-02 18:08:56.396 wetap[73922:60b] Waiting on location...
2014-04-02 18:08:56.396 wetap[73922:60b] my location is: 0.000000, 0.000000
2014-04-02 18:08:56.397 wetap[73922:60b] Location manager think's we're at: (null)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you have allocated an CLLocationManager and enabled location updates?

Comment: I've included the relevant (I think) controller code as well as the successful log output for when I run the simulator manually. @Paulw11

Answer (score -2):

The Google Map View is just a view, it doesn't automatically connect to the location tracking in iOS and update itself.  You need to allocate a CLLocationManager and track your location using it's delegate methods.  You can then update the myLocation property as in this answer -  [GMSMapView myLocation not giving actual location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366403/gmsmapview-mylocation-not-giving-actual-location)

I don't think you have set the delegate method for your CLLocationManager - it is the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method that will transfer the location to the Google Map View

in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

the implement the delegate method (note that the method referred to in the previous answer, `didUpdateLocation` has been deprecated and replaced with the `didUpdateLocations` method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *latestLocation=(CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];

    [self.mapView animateToLocation:latestLocation.coordinate]  <== this is the important bit - it transfers the location from CLLocationManager to the GM view

}
```

Refer to the [CLLocationManager reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Comment: The answer you linked to actually recommends using KVO updates rather than implementing the LocationManager delegate. But I did start to try what you recommended, and the LocationManager continuously gives me a null location. I changed my test loop - see edits.