# Doesn't Show Current location on google map?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google map sdk version 1.9.1.

I want to display map with current location .

here is my code.

```
@interface ViewController ()
 {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 320.0f, 300.0f) camera:nil];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview: mapView_];
}
```

but I can't display current location.
appreciate for help.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366403/gmsmapview-mylocation-not-giving-actual-location

Comment: Make sure your app accessing device's location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8. Try to set _yourMapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES and tap on this button?

Comment: I got location but it gives me wrong location. it returns location of "san Francisco" @phuongle

Comment: Let try other solution, listen Apple location by CLLocationManager:didUpdateLocations method. And then call [_mapView animateToLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees latitude, CLLocationDegrees longitude)] to update current location in Google Map.

Comment: In DidUpdate location I got wrong location when I updated ios 8.3 @phuongle

Answer (score 0):

You must set your location in

Debug>Location>custom lacation

Like

[image]

If you can test in device then enable your location in setting screen

Answer (score 0):

1. First your app has to ask permission for accessing user location in ios8. See this post: [Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8) or this: [iOS: App is not asking user's permission while installing the app. getting kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined every time - Objective-c & Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664928/ios-core-location-is-not-asking-users-permission-while-installing-the-app-get)
2. After that you call the location manager's  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] method.

Then you will see your current updated location.